# DbContext -> DbSet -> Where clause is missing (Entity Framework 6)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've read some tutorials with entity framework 6...

The basics are easy.

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    User u = context.Users.Find(1);
}
```

But how to use "Where" or something else on the "DbSet" with the users?

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
        : base("name=MyContext")
    {
        //this.Database.Log = Console.Write;
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Users

```
[Table("User")]
public class User : Base
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

And thats the problem which doesnt work.

```
string username = "Test";
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    User u = from user in context.Users where user.Username == username select user;
}
```

**Error:** There was no implementation of the query pattern for source type 'DbSet'. 'Where' is not found. Maybe a reference or a using directive for 'System.Link' is missing.

If i try to autocomplete the methods there are none.

[image: VS2013]

**Why it doesnt works? :(**

// Edit:
Adding System.Linq to the top of the file changes the functions of the problem above so that i havent a problem anymore.

But why the `where` is wrong now?

```
The type "System.Linq.IQueryable<User>" cant converted into "User" explicit. There already exists an explicit conversion. (Possibly a cast is missing)
```

[image: above doesnt work, bottom works]

Comment: is System.Linq reference added to namespace?

Comment: Wtf!? Adding "using System.Linq" at the top of the file where i use the string above fixed the problem... Funny thing... Can you recheck the question. I added a problem with is with System.Linq, too. Thanks!!

Comment: The query is returning a type of System.Linq.IQueryable<User> and you are trying to put it in a variable of type User. I guess you need First() on the end of the query.

Answer (score 55):

Thanks to @Grant Winney and @Joe.

Adding `using System.Linq;` to the namespace/top of the document where i'm tring the code above fixed the problem.

And using the line above it works for the first item of the list.

```
User user = (select user from context.Users where user.Username == username select user).First();
```

Comment: You saved my hour even 2019 with Entity Framework Core 3 preview

Answer (score 2):

The (second) problem is in what you expect:

```
User u = from user in context.Users where user.Username == username select user;
```

You're expecting a single element. But a `Where` clause returns a list (IEnumerable) of items. Even if there's only one entity that fits the where clause, it will still return a list (with a single item in it).

If you want a single item, you need to either take the `.First()` or the `.Single()` item of that list.

Some considerations:

- Either method I just mentioned can take a clause similar to how the where clause works. This means you can skip the `Where` and put the clause straight in this method.
- `Single` only works if only one element exists (fitting the clause). If two elements occur, an exception will be thrown.
- `First` works similar to `Single`, but it will not throw an exception if multiple items exist (fitting the clause). It will simply return the **first** element it finds (fitting the clause).