# VS Community 2015 MVC Template - Cannot access custom model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-identity

I'm currently learning Asp.NET MVC, I have started with the Ouf of the Box template from Vs2015 but I am having problems getting data from custom table

Goal: My Goal is to add a contact list for the standard ApplicationUser using the following class:

```
public class UserContact
{        
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Contact { get; set; }
}
```

I have also added the following to my Application User:

```
public virtual ICollection<UserContact> ContactsList { get; set; }
```

And the following line to my ApplicationDbContext:

```
public DbSet<UserContact> UserContacts { get; set; }
```

The problem is that when I try to access the USerContacts table from my custome controller ContactController using

```
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

var UserId = SomUserID  
db.UserContacts.Where(x => x.User == UserId)
```

The where clause does not get recognised at all. I have useed the commands
enable-migration

add-migration ContactsList

update-database

Which ran with no errors and the table is now in the database. But I am unable to access the table. why? what am I doing wrong?

Please note that according to VS it is as if the .Where function is not available on the DbSet in my case

And linq is imported as this is the standard when adding a new empty controller with Vs2015.

The Database was created during the update-database

But ApplicationDbContext : IdentiyDbContext class does not let me access any other tables including Contact class, so,
when I used in my controller

"db.UserContacts.Where < x => x.User == someID >();"

it doesn recognise what x.User is from the UserContact class.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I found a stack overflow post where the user was missing a using statement:

```
using System.Linq;
```

[DbContext -> DbSet -> Where clause is missing (Entity Framework 6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547603/dbcontext-dbset-where-clause-is-missing-entity-framework-6)

Comment: Appologies for the many typos in my question. but the equality operter is not the issue. The .Where()  function is not even recognised as an available function. But I will fix my question

Comment: Are you using entity framework?  I only ask because I never have to edit my dbcontext when using entity framework. Although I use db first in most projects but for me I just go to the diagram, chose update from database with a left click add the new DB table and my context is automagically updated.

Comment: Yes, I am using EF. and Linq is imported as is standard when adding and empty Controller.

Comment: db first or code first? see above I was editing my question when you responded

Comment: Have you checked the actual DB to see if the table was created as you intended?

Comment: Thanks Charles, I will review this now to see.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt help.
The problem is this solution uses a Custom DbContext class. I am using the standard ApplicationDbContext from the Vs2015 mvc Template. I have created projects inheriting from Dbcontext and I have been able to find my tables and query data not problem. But with the stardard template this is not working. If I try create a 2nd Dbcontext I get errors about Identity when I use enable-migrations.